# Error in rapidminer.init()

Tags: java, rapidminer

I'm new in integrating Rapid miner in Java applications and currently i'm having an exception in the rapidminer.init(). As far as i can understand its because od the repositories. But i don't know what to do. I did some research but i still cant resolve my problem. The exception is:

```
Dez 17, 2013 5:26:39 PM com.rapidminer.tools.ParameterService init
INFO: Reading configuration resource com/rapidminer/resources/rapidminerrc.
Dec 17, 2013 5:26:39 PM com.rapidminer.tools.I18N <clinit>
INFO: Set locale to en.
Dec 17, 2013 5:26:39 PM com.rapid_i.Launcher ensureRapidMinerHomeSet
INFO: Property rapidminer.home is not set. Guessing.
Dec 17, 2013 5:26:39 PM com.rapid_i.Launcher ensureRapidMinerHomeSet
INFO: Trying parent directory of 'C:\Documents and Settings\Geral\workspace\LinkMiningModule\Resources\RM5.3\launcher.jar'...gotcha!
Dec 17, 2013 5:26:39 PM com.rapid_i.Launcher ensureRapidMinerHomeSet
INFO: Trying parent directory of 'C:\Documents and Settings\Geral\workspace\LinkMiningModule\Resources\RM5.3\rapidminer.jar'...gotcha!
Dec 17, 2013 5:26:39 PM com.rapidminer.repository.RepositoryManager load
INFO: Cannot access file system in execution mode UNKNOWN. Not loading repositories.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vlsolutions/swing/docking/ui/DockingUISettings
    at com.rapidminer.tools.plugin.Plugin.initAll(Plugin.java:945)
    at com.rapidminer.RapidMiner.init(RapidMiner.java:550)
    at DataMinning.RapidMinnerInteraction.<init>(RapidMinnerInteraction.java:26)
    at dataBaseHandling.GatheringInformationFromDB.<init>(GatheringInformationFromDB.java:61)
    at General.InitializeEverything.<init>(InitializeEverything.java:22)
    at General.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vlsolutions.swing.docking.ui.DockingUISettings
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

My code is very simple:

```
public RapidMinnerInteraction()
    {

             RapidMinerCommandLine.init();

              Process process = null;
            try {
                process = new Process(new File("NeuralNetwork/NeuralNetworkProcess.rmp"));
                try {
                    process.run();
                } catch (OperatorException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }




    }
```

Any help would be awesome

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception it looks like you missed to add at least the `vldocking.jar` file to your classpath, possibly others are missing too.